# WordPress Accessible Keyboard Menus

Tags: menus

I am trying to make my WordPress Submenus appear when using the tab key.  I have tried adding the following in my styles without any luck:

```
header .nav .main .navigation #menu-main-navigation li:focus > ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could get this to work?

This currently works when hovering with a mouse pointer:

```
header .nav .main .navigation #menu-main-navigation li:hover > ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
```

Here is my menu code:

```
<ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-    object-page menu-item-home menu-item-21"><a href="/" class="local-link">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-22"><a href="/patients/" class="local-link">Patients</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-154" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-154"><a href="/differences" class="local-link">Differences</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-155"><a href="/team" class="local-link">Our Team</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With that structure, try this:

(note this makes assumptions about your base styles)

```
// your working styles, trimmed down
#menu-main-navigation li > ul.sub-menu { display: none; }
#menu-main-navigation li:hover > ul.sub-menu { display: block; }

// focus is on the link, not the li!
#menu-main-navigation li a:focus + ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
```